# android: Display single View from ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-arrayadapter, android-view, android-adapter

I got a `CustomAdapter`, which implements `ArrayAdapter`.
I use this Adapter in an activity `A` and I want to display the first element of this adapter in another (otherwise unrelated) activity `B`.

What would be the easiest way to display the view from the first element of the adapter?

I could get the view with `View view = arrayAdapter.getView(0);` How could I display this view?

Or I set the adapter to a container that accepts `ArrayAdapter`. Which container would work?

Comment: pass the first element data with intent to activity B and display it there

Comment: That doesn't help me. I get the view to Activity B. I just don't know how to display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I was looking for was:
Just take a layout and add the view to it. 
I used linear layout and the result was:

```
    linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.topLinearLayout);
    linearLayout.addView(customAdapter.getView(0, null, null), 1);
```